# Floor number to nearest quarter, to three decimal places?

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to round a float to the nearest quarter, with three decimal places, but I can't seem to do it in PHP. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$longitude = 145.6360003;
echo floor($longitude * 4) / 4;
```

I get `145.5` back, but the value I'm looking for is `145.625`. I also tried [this snippet from the php.net comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php#96568) but still nothing.

How do I trim a number to 3 decimal places, then round to the nearest quarter, preserving the three decimal places?

Comment: i understood you want to use a round function for making a number in 3 decimal figure, but how can you change `145.6360003` to  `145.625`?? It should be `145.636`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Because, as the question states, he wants the nearest quarter - but what he's really asking is the nearest eight.

Comment: oops....my eyes goes away.

Comment: I'm not clear what it means to "round to a quarter" if there are three decimal places - a quarter to three decimal places would be 0.250. Do you mean round to the nearest 40th (0.025)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.125 isn't the nearest quarter, it's the nearest eighth.

Your example is correct, if you want the nearest quarter, it's `145.5`. If you want the nearest eighth, that would be `145.625`:

```
>>> math.floor(lon * 8) / 8
145.625
```

or in PHP:

```
$longitude = 145.6360003;
echo floor($longitude * 8) / 8;
```

You should also consider having `round($result, 3)` as the last step because of the inherent inaccuracy of floating point numbers.

Comment: sir, If the number is `1231.245` then what will be the result??? I think it has to`1231.250`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense when you explain it that way. Thanks for the explanation and tip about rounding :)

Comment: Or did you want `floor($longitude * 40) / 40;`, the next-lowest quarter after the first decimal digit? -- In the example above, do you want to round to `1231.125` (8) or to `1231.225` (40)?

Comment: @MatsLindh:  Actually, while you're generally correct about the "inherent inaccuracy" of floating point numbers, this question is an exceptional case: while most questions ask for rounding to the tenth, hundredth, or another decimal place, this question asks for rounding to the nearest quarter, a binary decimal place which binary floating-point number implementations (like the one used in PHP) are well suited for.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Moreover, due to the intended application domain of the numbers (they're latitudes and longitudes), there is almost no practical risk of inaccuracy (besides the inaccuracy in measuring the coordinates themselves).

Comment: @PeterO. Sure - the inaccuracy is relevant for display only - to avoid suddenly having "0000000001" as the trailing value for a floating point number. And yes - the 1/8 is an exceptional case. Which is why the "safe" way should be chosen regardless, to avoid any sudden surprises later (if it's changed, manipulated in other ways, a different ratio is introduced, or if the future maintainer (or this maintainer) doesn't understand why 1/8 is exceptional).

Comment: @LutzL: I wound up fiddling and used 40, as it provided more "inaccuracy" for my purposes. My PHP script takes lat / long pairs (from a mobile app), makes them accurate to about 1300 feet and stores the results, plus a count, so I can make a heatmap of popular travel destinations. Cheers for the 40 hint :)